# Difference between imperfeito, pretérito perfeito, and pretérito perfeito/imperfeito do indicativo?

Tags: português-brasileiro, gramática, imperfeito-ou-perfeito

What is the different meanings of the past verb tenses in (Brazilian) Portuguese? I understand the general idea that the perfect preterite describes an action that completed in the past and the imperfect preterite describes a habitual or ongoing action, but I am really confused about the difference between something like 'estava chovendo' and 'chovia.'

Both seem to describe an ongoing action in the past, but I have a vague feeling that the first is like a one-time occurrence and the second describes something that tended to occur pretty often. Is there a correspondence to past forms in French, like 'j'avais eu' (I had had previously), 'j'avais' (I had), and 'j'ai eu' (I had had)?

For example:

**Perfect preterite**: choveu (it rained) describes a complete action that occurred in the past.

**Imperfect preterite**: chovia (it was raining)

**Indicative perfect preterite**: estava chovendo (it was raining)

**Indicative imperfect preterite**: choveu, same as standard imperfect preterite?

Here's another example: vinham/vieram/estavam vindo.

I am not sure the above labels are even correct, that is just my understanding from a grammatical book I have been trying to use.

Comment: Note that the names are supposed to be "**composite** indicative perfect preterit": the name "indicative perfect preterit" is the same as just "perfect preterit". See the header "indicativo" in this conjugation table: https://dicionario.priberam.org/Conjugar/chover

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your feeling is pretty much correct. ***Estava chovendo*** refers to a particular occasion or a particular point in time, such as the moment I left home:

> Quando eu saí de casa, **estava chovendo** muito [when I left home, it was raininig a lot]

You could in this example say “chovia muito”, but you’re more likely to find that in literature than in colloquial speech. But if you mean something that used to happen ― not just at one particular point in time ― then you use ***chovia***:

> Quando eu era criança, **chovia** mais do que agora [when I was a child it used to rain more than nowadays]

It’s the same with ***estavam vindo, vinham***

> Eles **estavam vindo** para casa quando eu os encontrei [they were coming home when I met them]
>
> Eles **vinham** cá muitas vezes [They used to come here often]

More examples:

> Eu **estava lendo**, e então faltou a luz [I was reading, and then the lights went out]
> Dantes eu **lia** o jornal todos os dias [I used to read the newspaper every day]
>
> Eu **estava** correndo, tropecei e caí [I was running, tripped and fell]
> Quando eu era mais novo, **corria** 10 km in 30 minutes [When I was younger I would run 10 km in 30 minutes]
>
> Eu **estava gostando** do livro, mas perdi o interesse no capítulo 10 [I was enjoying the book, but lost interest in chapter 10]
> Em criança eu não **gostava** de couves [When I was child I wouldn’t like cabbage]

I’m pretty sure there will be lots of complications, but this is the gist of it.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between *estava + <verb in present participle>* and *<verb in imperfect indicative>* depends on the verb in question and the context.

*Estava + <verb in present participle>*, just like in English, denotes the [progressive aspect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uses_of_English_verb_forms#Progressive). For starters, this rules it out with non-phaseable states (like **ele estava a saber*, **ele estava a ser alto*), as it essentially turns the situations into states — but, yes, not into *habitual states* (which are actually derived from e.g. a series of events).

As to the imperfect indicative, a first observation is that in its normal usage (read: excepting here modal uses such as in conditional sentences or for courtesy), it needs some sort of temporal framing — this can be a temporal clause with *quando/enquanto* or some adverbial expression like *muitas vezes*, *sempre*, *todos os meses* (quantification) or *ontem* (temporal location, for states). The imperfect then indicates a intersection (partial or total) with some past, or a relationship of inclusion. Because of this, the imperfect may also alter the aspect of verb, eliminating its culmination and possibly even turning it into a state. For a state or an activity (like *chover*), which is atelic anyway (i.e., they don't tend to some completion), the effect is not as pronounced, but in something like:

> Às 11h30, os mais retardatários ainda jantavam.

the culmination of *jantar* is lost and we can conclude they were dining before that time, and at the time of reference.

So the imperfect can, by itself, operate an aspect change close to *estar + <present participle>*, an indeed you could say *estava jantando* above. Likewise, *quando cheguei a casa, chovia a potes* and *quando cheguei a casa, estava chovendo a potes* are indistinguishable, though I agree with Jacinto that, in many cases, there is a small difference in register.

Only the imperfect, however, can describe habitual states:

> Quando ligava a ventoinha, ela espirrava.
>   *Quando ligava a ventoinha, ela estava espirrando.

*Espirrar*, being a [semelfactive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semelfactive), has no internal structure to focus, but the first sentence can instead be be read to mean *every time I turned on the fan, she sneezed*. This reading is not possible in the second sentence.

And in general, every time we use quantifiers such as *sempre*, *todos os meses*, *com frequência*, etc, *estava + <verb in present participle>* is not an option:

> Antigamente, chovia durante o mês de Junho.
>   Ele jantava semanalmente em casa do amigo.

Comment: Pois, isto é muito bom, como habitualmente. Mas tu tás-te um bocado nas tintas para o leitor.